# Unable to use select match in ansible 2.8

Tags: select, ansible

For this piece of code

```
"{{ recap_check.split('-')[1:] | select('!=','linux') | join('_') }}"
```

I am getting this error:

> TemplateRuntimeError: no test named '!='

Same piece of code runs fine in 2.7.
It is possible that the variable I am sending in to the task is not  being loaded.

Comment: This looks like you have an xyproblem with all those split-select-join things going on there -- what are you actually trying to do with that expression?

Comment: I indeed wonder if a `json_query` + `replace` wouldn't be more suited here, but without an example and a desired result, it is hard to tell.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Tested in a virtualenv with ansible 2.8.12, python 3.6.9, Jinja2 2.11.2 (`virtualenv ans2.8 && . ./ans2.8/bin/activate && pip install 'ansible<2.9' && ansible-playbook test.yml`). All works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i dont know why the select doesn't work but this is how have it solved.
After printing out a whole lot of debugs

recap_check = 0-ueg-eeprom-linux

```
recap_role: "{{ recap_check.split('-')[1:2] | join('_') }}"
```

the select filter for '!~' or 'ne' doesnt work in ansible2.8 environment.

Answer (score 0):

[`select`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#select) is using the [builtin tests](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-tests) from Jinja.
In the above list of tests, you can see that *not equal* is actually [`ne`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#ne).

So you Jinja line should be:

```
"{{ recap_check.split('-')[1:] | select('ne', 'linux') | join('_') }}"
```